# VBA to loop through each link in the left column of an IE table

Tags: html, vba, click, html-table

This may be something quite simple that I have missed but I have been trying to resolve this issue for over a week and it's driving me nuts.

I am trying to loop through an intranet table clicking each of the links in the left column. Each link brings up a sub-table that I collect the data from, I then use ie.back returning to the first table to click on the next link.

this is what I have so far:-

```
Sub CycleShiftIDs()
    Dim Table_Element As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim tbl As Object, Click As Object, td As Object

    For Each tbl In Table_Element
        If tbl.className = "mytable" Then
        For Each td In Table_Element.getElementsByTagName("td")
            If td.innerText = "A" Then
                Set Click = Table_Element.getElementById("linkOff")
                Click.Click
                Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
                Call GetTableData
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

The table data from the intanet site looks like this:-

```
<TABLE class=mytable>
<TBODY>
<TR class=ScreenOnlyDispNone bgColor=silver>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">Shift</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">FullName</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">Assc</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">Date</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">Cases</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">Std</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">Act</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">Perf</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">Dy hh:MM:ss</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">PickRate</TD></TR>
<TR bgColor=lightblue>
<TD id=tblShiftData style="WIDTH: 35px"><A onclick="RunRptTot _ 
      '60','S'"id=linkOff href="">60</A></TD>
<TD id=tblFullNameData style="WIDTH: 130px"></TD>
<TD id=tblAsscIDData style="WIDTH: 50px"></TD>
<TD id=tblDateData style="WIDTH: 55px"></TD>
<TD id=tblCasesData>561788</TD>
<TD id=tblStdData>128454.98</TD>
<TD id=tblActData>162753.19</TD>
<TD id=tblPerfData style="WIDTH: 50px">78.93</TD>
<TD id=tblhhMMssData style="TEXT-ALIGN: right">113d&nbsp;00:33:11</TD>
<TD id=tblPickRateData style="WIDTH: 60px">207.11</TD></TR>
<TR bgColor=lightblue>
<TD><A onclick="RunRptTot '61','S'" id=linkOff href="">61</A></TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD></TD>
.........
```

Any ideas on how I should proceed?

The next procedure is

```
Sub GetTableData()
Application.StatusBar = " Collecting the data on performances"
Dim i As Integer
Sheets("Capture").Visible = True
Sheets("Capture").Select
Append = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
OffSet1 = 0
Set TR_Element = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("TR")
    For Each HTMLRow In TR_Element
    Set TD_Element = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("TR")_  
                           (OffSet1).getElementsByTagName("TD")
        OffSet2 = 0
        For Each HTMLCol In TD_Element
            Cells(Append, 1).Offset(OffSet1, OffSet2).Value = _ 
                                              HTMLCol.innerText
            OffSet2 = OffSet2 + 1
            Cells(Append, 1).Offset(OffSet1, OffSet2).Value = "Picking"
        Next HTMLCol
    OffSet1 = OffSet1 + 1
Next HTMLRow
IE.GoBack
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
   End Sub
```

I Just call this procedure and return to the first table.

Comment: You could make a great start by telling us what happens and explaining how it's not what you want?  You haven't specified what it is that isn't working, which makes it very difficult to help you out... We could also use the code from GetTableData so we can see what that step is doing.

Comment: every time I run the code I get an error message that i'm doing some outside procedure wrong. I have re written this so many times and tried several diffrent ways of getting this to loop through the table. I can see that certain aspects are constant like "linkOff" and "A" and although I can click the button I can't get it to go to the next row and do it again. It's frustrating as I know it's something simple that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

With Help from John_w on another forum the problem is resolved. I did keep getting a 'Code 70 Permission Denied' however repeating the 'Set MyTable' seems to have resolved this.

```
Sub CycleShfts()
Dim MyTable As HTMLTable
Dim r As Integer
Set htmldoc = IE.document
Set MyTable = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(5)
    For r = 1 To MyTable.Rows.Length - 1
        Set MyTable = htmldoc.getElementsByTagName("table")(5)
        MyTable.Rows(r).Cells(0).FirstChild.Click
            Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Call GetTableData
    Next
End Sub
```